# How to correctly override configure method of tkinter widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need an entry widget that keeps a reference to its textvariable (because the associated variable may change during runtime).

Since `some_entry['textvariable']` returns a useless string, I wrote my own class.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class MyEntry(ttk.Entry, object):
    'entry that keeps a reference to its textvariable'
    def __init__(self, master, textvariable, *args, **kwargs):
        self.textvariable = textvariable
        super(MyEntry, self).__init__(
            master, *args, textvariable=textvariable, **kwargs)

    def configure(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.textvariable = kwargs.get('textvariable', self.textvariable)
        return super(MyEntry, self).configure(*args, **kwargs)
```

This works as expected:

```
python -i mcve.py
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> var1 = tk.StringVar(value='v1')
>>> var2 = tk.StringVar(value='v2')
>>> e = MyEntry(root, textvariable=var1)
>>> 
>>> e.textvariable.get()
'v1'
>>> e.configure(textvariable=var2)
>>> e.textvariable.get()
'v2'
```

However, setting the textvariable through the `[]` notation fails.

```
>>> e['textvariable'] = var1
>>> e.textvariable.get()
'v2'
```

**Attempt**

Currently I am simply using

```
def __setitem__(self, what, value):
    self.configure(**{what:value})
```

Am I messing up anything by not calling the superclasses' `__setitem__` here? The solution seems to work, but I don't know enough about the `Tkinter` internals to be confident that it won't break in some scenarios.

Comment: ***"variable may change"***: Bad approach, but regardless, you have to implement [object.__setattr__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) to enable your `class MyEntry(` to be **subscriptable**.

Comment: @stovfl I don't think it's fair to judge the approach without knowing the program. The entry is bound to variables with different input validation (via `trace`) based on options the user can set. Anyway, I think it's `__setitem__`. :)